# How to add counter number to the current hash on click, without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, hash

How can I add the counter or ids to the hash without refreshing the page, so that  if I click on "back" button I go back to the previous hash and ho can I implement the back button:

here is the sample of the code:
[http://jsfiddle.net/KFUVq/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/KFUVq/12/%22Sample%22)

```
$('.a').click(function () {
    counter++;
    var current_id = counter;
    $('.counter').text(current_id);//show the counter value
    $('.b').addClass('hidden');//hide all  
    $('.page1text1[id="' + current_id + '"]').removeClass('hidden');//show the required
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.hash`, which references the hash of the current page:

```
$('.a').click(function () {
    counter++;
    var current_id = counter;
    $('.counter').text(current_id);//show the counter value
    $('.b').addClass('hidden');//hide all  
    $('.page1text1[id="' + current_id + '"]').removeClass('hidden');//show the required
    window.location.hash = '#' + current_id;//set page hash
});
```

Comment: but the page is getting refreshed to #1 it doesnt stay at e.g. page1#1